# React Native com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base version bug

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting the following error on my React Native project when trying to launch on Android.  I launched successfully last night, didn't make any changes and am now getting this error somehow.  Does anyone know how to solve this?

**Error**

> - What went wrong: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:checkDebugClasspath' property 'compileClasspath' during up-to
>     -date check.
>
>   > The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [ [16.0.5,16.0.5],
>   >     [16.3.0,16.3.0]], but resolves to 16.3.0. Disable the plugin and check
>   >     your dependencies tree using . /gradlew :app:dependencies.

**Troubleshooting steps**

I've tried updating implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1" in app/build.gradle to 16.0.5 and 16.0.3 and neither has worked.

**build.gradle dependencies section**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-photo-view')
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
}
```

**full build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wherewedroppinboysbenji"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 3
        versionName "3.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-photo-view')
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**package.json dependencies**

```
{
  "name": "reactnativeproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "^16.6.1",
    "react-native": "^0.57.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-photo-view": "git+https://github.com/tomtom94/react-native-photo-view.git",
    "react-native-photo-view-ex": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-rate": "^1.1.6",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.12.1",
    "react-navigation-props-mapper": "^0.3.0",
    "react-navigator": "0.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1",
    "react-devtools-core": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to resolve your dependencies in your `android/app/build.gradle`. There is a conflict between your dependencies import different version of `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base` I would suggest posting your `build.gradle`

Comment: @Andrew good call.  I just added my full gradle.build and also included the dependencies section of build.gradle in its own section to easily find it

Comment: I removed react-native-google-analytics-bridge and it's working perfectly now!

Comment: That’s great that it is now working. There is always one dependency that causes an issues

Comment: @Andrew I know!  I'm learning that the hard way.  At least this way I won't easily forget.  Thanks for your help!